# Parameters to Catch?

Tags: c#, try-catch

Is it possible to pass parameters to a catch block?
Here is some example code:

```
try 
{           
    myTextBox.Text = "Imagine, that could fail";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message); 
}
```

Can I pass the Textbox (**myTextBox**) now to my catch block if it would fail? smth. like that:

```
try 
{           
    myTextBox.Text = "Imagine, that could fail";
}
catch (Exception e, TextBox textBox)
{
    textBox.BorderBrush = Colors.Red;
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message); 
}
```

How I would do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not possible by standart.

What you *can* do, is to define your custom exception and assign parameters there, for example:

```
public class MyCustomException : Exception
{
    public string SomeAdditionalText {get;set;}
    ....
    //any other properties
    ...
}
```

and inside the method which raises an exception raise your own `MyCustomException`

Answer (score 6):

You only `catch` a single thing, which in C# must be an `Exception`. So not directly. However! If the `Exception` were, say, a custom `SomethingSpecificException`, then you could make that information available on `e.SomeProperty`.

```
public class SomethingSpecificException : Exception {
    public Control SomeProperty {get;private set;}
    public SomethingSpecificException(string message, Control control)
          : base(message)
    {
       SomeProperty = control;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then at some point you could:

```
throw new SomethingSpecificException("things went ill", ctrl);
```

and

```
catch(SomethingSpecificException ex) {
    var ctrl = ex.SomeProperty;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a little overkill, regarding to the question? =)

Comment: @Mario most programs/contexts are more complex than just a 10-line SO question; it is reasonable to assume that the question is a cut-down version of the real thing. So: maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Maybe so. But I was thinking that you probably have an *easier* solution to the context given.

Answer (score 1):

don't know what you want to achieve, but in the catch block you can access any UI element, as you do in the try block. So for me there is no point of defining an additional parameter in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the possibility to use custom exception to distinguish what's going on:

```
try
{
    myClass.DoSomethingThatCouldThrow();
    myClass.DoSomethingThatThrowsSomethingElse();
    myClass.DoAnotherThingWithAThirdExceptionType();
}
catch(FirstSpecialException ex)
{
    // Do something if first fails...
}
catch(SecondSpecialException ex)
{
    // Do something if second fails...
}
```

You could also put every statement into its own exception block. This would make your code quite lengthly, but is maybe the only possibility if you can't change the class to throw any special exception.

```
try
{
    myClass.DoSomethingThatCouldThrow();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // Do something if it fails...
}

try
{
    myClass.DoSomethingThatCouldThrow();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // Do something if it fails...
}

try
{
    myClass.DoAnotherThingWithAThirdExceptionType();
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // Do something if it fails...
}
```

Due to the fact, that this last, looks a little bit like repetitive code, we could maybe put it into some method with the following body:

```
public void TryCatch<ExceptionT>(Action tryMethod, Action<ExceptionT> catchMethod)
    where ExceptionT : Exception
{
    // ToDo: ArgumentChecking!

    try
    {
        tryMethod();
    }
    catch(ExceptionT ex)
    {
        catchMethod(ex);
    }
}
```

Which could you then call with:

```
TryCatch<InvalidOperationException>(
    () => myClass.DoSomething(),
    (ex) => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));
```